# Why does hand sanitizer heat up?

Tags: heat

While washing my hands with soap I added some hand sanitizer just because it was right there on the counter and couldn't resist mixing them... Ha!  However, when I added the hand sanitizer it heated up for a moment and then cooled back down.  Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Hand sanitizers are generally ~50% - 70% ethanol or isopropanol. [When these alcohols mix with water, they may release heat.](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/je60034a008) [Starting at room temperature, mixing ~100% ethanol with an equal volume of water will raise the temperature of the mixture ~8 <sup>0</sup>C.](http://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/presentations/mixing-ethanol-and-water)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like some type of exothermic reaction happened between the hand sanitizer which is primarily alcohol, and the soap.